# fetch in redux action does nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch-api

I am trying to refactor my app so that it works with redux. I have a redux action where the first console.log produces output (line 3 below which shows the api url). No other output seen. Also catch seems not to be called (I tested it).

fetch seems to do nothing. The fetch code snipped worked however when it was on its original place (before refactoring) within componentWillMount.

What's wrong with my fetch? Thank you for any help!

```js
export function getPlatzBelegungen(court, day1, day2) {
  const url = HOSTNAME + "/intern/api/platz.php?op=ra&p=" + court + "&ds=" + day1 + "&de=" + day2;
  console.log(url);
  
  return function(dispatch) {
    return fetch(url)
    .then(result => {
      if (result.ok) {
        console.log("###>>> result.ok");
          return result.json();
        } else {
          throw new Error('Fehler beim Laden der Platzbuchungsdaten');
        }
    })
    .then(result => {
        console.log("###>>> courtData berechnen");
        let courtData = result.records.map ( r => {
        let k = r.id;
        let cn = computeBelClasses (r.starts_at, r.ends_at);
        console.log("PLATZ:" + r.court)
        let spieler = 
            r.p1 
          + (r.p2 ? ', ' + r.p2 : ' ') 
          + (r.p3 ? ', ' + r.p3 : ' ') 
          + (r.p4 ? ', ' + r.p4 : ' ');
        return ( 
          <Link key={k} to={'/belegungsdetails/' + r.id}>
            <div key={k} className={cn}>
              <strong>{r.starts_at.substring(11,16)} </strong>
              {spieler}
            </div>
          </Link>
        )
      })
      dispatch({ type: BELEGUNGEN_LOADED, payload: courtData });
    })
    .catch(
      dispatch({ type: BELEGUNGEN_LOAD_FAILED, payload: [] }));
  };

};
```

Comment: What is the expected result of `.catch(
      dispatch({ type: BELEGUNGEN_LOAD_FAILED, payload: [] }))`? Does `dispatch()` return a function?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have some errors for the fetch. Your catch part needs to pass a function into it. Like

```
.catch(error => {
    dispatch({ type: BELEGUNGEN_LOADED, payload: courtData });
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately removing "return" does not help